# Telescoping series sum $ \arctan(n + 5) - \arctan(n + 4) $.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the telescoping series sum of $ \arctan(n + 5) - \arctan(n + 4) $ from $ n = 1 $ to $ \infty $.

Is $ S_{n} = \arctan(-5) - \arctan(n + 5) $?

As I let $ n \to \infty $, the sum would be $ -1.37 - 1.5707078 = -2.944 $.

I’m uncertain about my answer, but please check it. If it’s wrong, please show me where I’ve made a mistake.

Comment: All the terms you are adding are positive --- you can't get a negative sum.

Comment: $S_n=\arctan(-5)+\arctan(n+5)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_1^N(\arctan(n+5)-\arctan(n+4))=\arctan6-\arctan5+\arctan7-\arctan6+\cdots+\arctan(N+5)-\arctan(N+4)=\arctan(N+5)-\arctan5$

Taking the limit as $N\to\infty$ yields $(\pi/2)-\arctan5$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the first $n$ terms is 
$$(\arctan 6-\arctan 5)+(\arctan 7-\arctan 6)+ \cdots+(\arctan(n+5)-\arctan(n+4)).$$
There is massive cancellation: the sum of the first $n$ terms is $\arctan(n+5)-\arctan(5)$. As $n\to\infty$, this approaches $\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\arctan 5$. 
The numerical calculation went a little astray. To a few decimal places, I get $0.1973956$.

Comment: thank you very much to you too.

Comment: You are welcome. Your calculation was close, but then somehow minus signs crept in.